# Alfresco hibernate integration

Tags: java, hibernate, alfresco

I am using Alfresco Community Alfresco v5.0.1.

I built an alfresco content type and a Java Bean matching that content type.
Could I use hibernate or other framework to perform the mapping?

Comment: Fixed few grammatical issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alfresco has moved away from Hibernate as an ORM to MyBatis.

Actually configuring a MyBatis connector to your database takes a bit of explanation and likely falls outside of the scope of an SO answer but the following are some resources that will help you set one up.

Alfresco Devcon 2012 presentation on setting up MyBatis: http://www.slideshare.net/slemarchand/using-mybatis-in-alfresco-custom-extensions-alfresco-devcon-2012-berlin

2013 blog:
http://www.shi-gmbh.com/blog/2013/integrating-mybatis-in-alfresco-web-scripts

From your description however it doesn't sound like this is what you want. If you have added your type to the model then you don't need to manually add it to MyBatis. Your type is just the property of a node that can be used in the same way as you do a node of any other type.

```
// create new content node within company home
// assign name
String name = "Foundation API sample (" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ")";

// create content node
NodeService nodeService = registry.getNodeService();
ChildAssociationRef association = nodeService.createNode(
        companyHome,
        ContentModel.ASSOC_CONTAINS,
        QName.createQName(NamespaceService.CONTENT_MODEL_PREFIX, name),
        ContentModel.TYPE_CONTENT);
```

And replace `ContentModel.TYPE_CONTENT` with your own type.

Answer (score 0):

Few yeras ago I did an extension for Alfresco Explorer (I don't remember the version but at this time it was in JSF 1.2) and I used Hibernate with Alfresco's DB so at now, I think, should work too...